# list process based on tcp port

Tags: linux, bash, alias, ps

Help me setting an alias that represents this command:

```bash
ps -u -p $(fuser 5432/tcp 2>/dev/null)

#output:
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
postgres  423310  0.0  0.1 506528 14544 ?        S    Jun25   1:48 /usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgres
```

I have tried:
`alias p2p='ps -u -p $(fuser $1 2>/dev/null)'`, but it doesn't work

Comment: Aliases can't take arguments. Write a shell function.

Comment: maybe they shouldn't ,  but they can .

Comment: I mean you can't reference them like `$1`. The alias is simply expanded before all the arguments.

Comment: Isn't this a XY-problem? Maybe `netstat` is better?

Comment: No @barmar, simple quotes don't expand arguments

Comment: I know. But when you execute the alias, it won't substitute `$1` from the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like I've found something that works.

Like @Barmar commented, a function works, but `fuser` insists in writing to error ouput.

So I did a `function` and a `alias` that mutes `stderr` of `fuser` output:

```bash
function p2pfunc() { PID=$(fuser $@); echo "PID =$PID"; ps -u -p $PID; }
alias p2p='p2pfunc $@ 2>/dev/null'

p2p 5432/tcp 5433/tcp

PID =  3055 423310
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
postgres    3055  0.0  0.1 506664 12120 ?        S    May16   4:03 /usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgres
postgres  423310  0.0  0.1 506528 14544 ?        S    Jun25   1:48 /usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to write your command in a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=$1
ps -u -p $(fuser $pid 2>/dev/null)
```

Then create your alias like:

```
alias pr='yourscript.sh'
```

A the end just call your alias like:

```
pr 5432/tcp
```

This is not such a good practice but it should work in your case.

Hope this help 
Regards

Comment: Thanks, but I did not want to deal with scripts in this case.

Comment: Ah ok, you're welcome.

Comment: Note: `pr` is the name of an existing command from [`coreutils`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pr.1p.html). As this it is also part of the POSIX standard. I suggest to use a different name for the alias to avoid unwanted side-effects